# How To add rules.pl file in gerrit to customise workflow

Tags: git, gerrit

I am working with Gerrit and I am new to it. I was trying to customize workflow by adding rules.pl file. But I am confused how to add. As per the documentation given [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/prolog-cookbook.html#HowToWriteSubmitRules)

It is given that we have to perform the check out of the origin. Now I have executed the following commands.

```
$ git remote add origin "url of my gerrit repository"

$ git pull origin refs/meta/config
```

I see that the Gerrit repository is a BARE: master which contains only version history and no working files.

When the code mentioned above is executed I see the message:

> fatal: C:\Program Files\Git/libexec/git-core\git-pull cannot be used
>   without a working tree

.

It would be great if someone could help in sorting this out. Also if there is some other way to add rules.please kindly mention that also.

Thanks

Comment: Your current git is a bare git. Why is that? While the original git on the server is bare, your local one shouldn't be.

Comment: I had created a project using gerrit. And the repository thus created is a bare repository

Comment: On the server, yes. But that's not where you're supposed to do the pulling. Clone the git locally if you want to make changes to it.

Comment: @MagnusBäck     I think you have misunderstood the context. I am working with gerrit and I have to add rules.pl file in refs/meta/config path as mentioned in the tutorial which I have mentioned above. The thing is I dont find the path in the local.

Comment: I understand the context fully. And I'm saying that you need to pull the refs/meta/config _ref_ (not _path_) into a local non-bare git. Do not attempt to modify the git on the server. Once you've pulled refs/meta/config, make your changes in your local git and push them back to your Gerrit server.

Comment: @MagnusBäck : Yeah I understand that and I performed the following operation.

% mkdir tmp 

% cd tmp 

% git init 

% git pull ssh://<username>@<Gerrit-URL>:29418/<project-name> refs/meta/config

When I executed the above command what I got is the following message

fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/meta/config
Unexpected end of command stream

Comment: Okay. Sounds like you don't have read permissions to that ref. I _think_ that ref is always available in Gerrit projects.

Comment: @MagnusBäck
In the configuration file of remote git I see that
[remote "origin"] fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

I think this is the reason why I cannot fetch refs/meta/config.

Could you help me to sort this out

Comment: No, that's not the problem. That setting only affects what's fetched when you don't specify a refspec, but you're explicitly passing `refs/meta/config` so it'll be ignored.

Comment: @MagnusBäck Actually I had installed gerrit on my Windows system. Version ins 2.9.1. Which means I should have the read permissions as the server is on my local system itself. Then what would be the reason for not being able to pull refs/meta/config

Comment: Since you appear to be fetching through SSH the file system permissions are irrelevant. Have you verified in Gerrit's access permissions view that you actually have read access to the refs/meta/config ref?

Comment: @MagnusBäck Thank you so much. I could solve it. It was right. I had to make the change in Gerrit's Access for refs/meta/config